# How to disable button if it is clicked from another computer

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have two computers running the same VB.net application. What I want to do is to disable a button if the same button on the other computer is already clicked. For example, if I want to add a new product, the ID_Code will come from the number of rows in database table. So when I try to add a new product and press confirm simultaneously from two computers, it adds two products with the same ID_Code. I don't know how it happens since i put the ID_Code in the primary key. Is there a way to disable a button so it can't be clicked simultaneously? Here's my code.

First get the number of rows in the table (MySql Database using switch as connection)

```
Private Sub getIDRow()
    Dim getYear As String = Now.Year
    countRow = 0
    mySqlConn = New MySqlConnection()
    mySqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server=" & servername & "; user id=edward; password=edward123; database=inventory;"
    Try
        mySqlConn.Open()
        myQuery = "Select * from inventory." & tblName
        myCommand = New MySqlCommand(myQuery, mySqlConn)
        myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
        While myDataReader.Read
            countRow = countRow + 1
        End While
        mySqlConn.Close()

        If countRow = 0 Then
            countRow = 1
            lblIdCode.Text = getYear & Now.ToString("") & countRow.ToString("0000")
        Else
            countRow = countRow + 1
            lblIdCode.Text = invCode & getYear & countRow.ToString("0000")
        End If
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to database: " & myerror.Message)
    Finally
        mySqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

And here's the code when I click the confirm button.

```
  mySqlConn = New MySqlConnection()
        mySqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server=" & servername & "; user id=edward; password=edward123; database=inventory;"
        Try
            mySqlConn.Open()
            myQuery = "INSERT INTO " & tblName & "(IdCode, Particular, Unit, Qty, Price, UnitVal, Type,CritQty)" & _
                        " VALUES(@IdCode, @Particular, @Unit, @Quantity, @Price, @UnitVal, @Type,@CritQty)"
            Using myCommand As New MySqlCommand(myQuery, mySqlConn)
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCode", lblIdCode.Text)
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Particular", txtAdParticular.Text)
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitVal", txtAdUnit.Text)
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unit", cmbAdUnit.Text)
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txtAdPrice.Text)
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", txtAdQuantity.Text)
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", tblName)
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CriQty", txtAdCritQty.Text)
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
            MsgBox("Add item successful!", vbInformation)
            mySqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to database: " & ex.Message)
        Finally
            mySqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try
```

Or could you please suggest a way to make it better.

Comment: And if you have 3, 4, etc... computers?. This is not how it is supposed to be done. Learn about AUTONUMBERcolumns.

Comment: *Classic* [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) post!

Answer (score 2):

You should modify your `IdCode` column to be an `AUTONUMBER` column. In this way, the value inserted in that column is calculated by the database engine.
You don't need to worry how many computers try to insert simultaneously a record in your table. The engine will calculate the value and put it in the column's record for you, accurately enqueuing the incoming requests.

This means that you don't need any code to calculate yourself the value and in your insert query you don't pass any value for the column with the AUTONUMBER flag.

If you need to know the number inserted by the engine you could call the command `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` using the same MySqlConnection used to issue the INSERT command

Said that I also suggest to change your code that adds the parameters to the MySqlCommand and use the more precise `Parameters.Add(name, dbtype).Value` approach. The AddWithValue method is very dangerous if you don't know how it executes the automatic conversion of values. Read [Can we stop to use AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Thanks for information. Im new in vb.net so i donk know much about addwithvalue. Ill try to code it when im get home. Thanks again for the answer :) Ill comment again if theres something wrong but i will try to search first before asking.